# Jquery & Variable ID Names

Tags: jquery

I am trying to avoid having the same code for different ids.  Something like submitter1, submitter2, etc. In the same process, having the variable also used to get the input box id of differentlocation1, differentlocation2, etc.  Can someone help me out with the code below?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#submitter<--Variable Here-->').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var newlocation = $("input[name=differentlocation"<--Same Variable Here-->"']");
        alert(newlocation); //testing purposes
        //$('#location').val(newlocation).change(); //Changes location input box
        //$("#submit").click(); //submits new location

    });
});
```

This code works using static ids, but like I said I would like to adjust it to use variable ids as well.

Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you use a class name to associate elements with the shared behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [*attribute starts with* selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$('button[id^="submitter"]').click(...);
```

Inside the `click` function, you can get the `id` using simple string methods:

```
var uuid = this.id.slice(9),
    newlocation = $('input[name="differentlocation'+uuid+'"]');
```

**Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wy8X9/**

Comment: @ Andy E Does this look right: `$('button[id^="submitter"]').click(function(event)` The id submitter is a button

Comment: I also have `var uuid = this.id.slice(9); alert(uuid);` It doesn't throw an alert.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @Go3Team: I'd double-check your code.  I posted an example link in my answer, that might help you.

Answer (score 1):

The proper solution is using a class instead of an ID since multiple elements can have the same class. To reference the input with the same variable part, you can then use (a part of) the ID or even better, a data field (`data-whatever="..."` in HTML, `$(elem).data('whatever')` in JS)

Answer (score 1):

Set IDs as data-id and point them like this

```
<tag class="submitter" data-id="n">

$('.submitter').click(function(){
  id = $(this).attr('data-id');
var newlocation = $("input[name=differentlocation"+id+"']");
})
```

Comment: I'm using hidden input type so I have: `var newlocation = $("hidden[name=differentlocation"+id+"']");` If I do `alert(newlocation);` The alert window says `object Object` - any thoughts?

Comment: $("hidden[name=differentlocation"+id+"']").val()

Answer (score 1):

When doing something that you want to share, I would recommend that you associate the even based on a common class name.

You can read `this.id` to get the ID of the event target and manipulate there.

```
$('.submitter').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var numId = this.id.replace(/[^0-9]+/, ''),
        newlocationId = "input[name=differentlocation" + numId+ "']";

    alert(newlocationId);
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/qud32/

Alternatively, you can use the "attribute starts with" selector as Andy suggests.