# Clicking on variable ID item triggers function in corresponding variable ID in other object in jQuery

Tags: jquery, click

I have a series of thumbs which I want a click on one to activate the appearance of the corresponding image. Without writing a script for each thumbnail-image pair I'm looking for a way for an image with id="thumb1" to trigger the appearance of and image with id="photo1" and so on.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952022/jquery-variable-id-names) and tried to implement it thus:

```
  $(function(){
$('img[id^="thumb"]').click(function () {
    $('img[id^="photo"]').show();
});
});
```

However, all the thumbs labelled "thumb1", "thumb2" etc all trigger the photo labelled "photo4" (the last in the series).

Any suggestions? Much thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is something like this you want?

```
$(function(){
    $('img[id^="thumb"]').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('thumb', '');
        $('img#photo' + id).toggle();
    });
});
```

When you click on a thumb, it displays or hides the corresponding photo.

Comment: Yes! That's exactly it. Thank you so much.

Comment: How would you make the photo fadeIn using something like this?

Comment: Just figured it out: you replace .toggle with .fadeIn