# Jquery change image source depending on id of div clicked

Tags: jquery, swap, thumbnails

I want a click on a thumb to reveal a larger image with a pre-loader and then a fade-in when loading is complete.

I am almost there thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287967/clicking-on-variable-id-item-triggers-function-in-corresponding-variable-id-in-o) - which enables different images to load depending on what thumb is clicked - and [this guide](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/image-loading/) which sorts out the loading bit.

Combining the two I have the following script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    $(function () {
        $('img[id^="thumb"]').click(function () {
        $('#loader').show();
        var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('thumb', '');
        var img = new Image();
        $(img).load(function () {
            //$(this).css('display', 'none');
            $(this).hide();
            $('#loader').removeClass('loading').append(this);
            $(this).fadeIn();
        }).attr('src', 'photos/1.jpg');
    }); });

    //-->
    </script>
```

You will notice at the end that the .attr source is fixed on one image. What I want is that the number before the '.jpg' changes depending on the id of the thumb (they are labelled: 'thumb1', 'thumb2' etc.)

Is there any way of doing this? Much thanks!

ps
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540349/change-the-image-source-using-jquery) seems to be close but the problem I have is that the thumb id seems to be too early on in script to be able to use such simple solutions.

Comment: I recommend you to have a look at Javascript Closures, that will clear your confusion about "the thumb id seems to be too early on in script to be able to use such simple solutions"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $('img[id^="thumb"]').click(function () {
        var thumbId = $(this).attr('id').substring(5); // assuming the id of the thumb is like "thumb1", "thumb2", ...
        $('#loader').show();
        var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('thumb', '');
        var img = new Image();
        $(img).load(function () {
            //$(this).css('display', 'none');
            $(this).hide();
            $('#loader').removeClass('loading').append(this);
            $(this).fadeIn();
        }).attr('src', 'photos/' + thumbId + '.jpg');
    }); });


    </script>
```